# doesn't do everything vs doesn't do anything

Tags: negation, any-every

I am creating a summary for English and I thought to myself: which is the correct form?

- the NSA doesn’t do everything by the book and lies about multiple facts.
- the NSA doesn't do anything by the book and lies about multiple facts.

Comment: Idiomatically, ***multiple*** would be relatively unusual in this context (***many, several, numerous** [things]* are more likely).

Answer (score 5):

The two sentences have different meanings, so which is 'correct' depends on what you're trying to say.

> the NSA doesn’t do everything by the book and lies about multiple facts.

This means the statement that they do *everything* by the book is false. In other words, **there are *some* things they don't do by the book.**

> the NSA doesn't do anything by the book and lies about multiple facts.

This means the statement that they do *anything* by the book is false. In other words, **there's *nothing* they do by the book.**